# "moment" format date with only a year or month and a year

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, momentjs

I have a string that represents a date in format of "YYYYMMDD", I need to format it to a different format.

I am using moment.

```
import moment from 'moment';

getDateStr(date: string, format){
    return moment(date, 'YYYYMMDD').format(format);
}
```

The problem is that if a get a partial date the string is rapped with "01" instead of the missing parameters.

For example if format is "YYYY-MM-DD" and the date is "201003" I get "2010-03-01", I want to get "2010-03".

How can I make it work in a generic way?

Comment: moment("201003", "YYYY-MM").format("YYYY-MM")?

Comment: Sometimes date is indeed full date, and I don't know what format itself will be.

Comment: would you add some examples?

Comment: sure, the format can be "MM-DD-YY" and date will be "20100302", tehre is a lot of options.

Comment: moment(date).format(format) ? pass in valid date and format options

Comment: it does not work.. for "201605" I got "01-01-201605" for "DD-MM-YYYY" format.

Comment: @danda If you cannot know the format of the date, you will run into problems. It may help to boil down the list to potential formats, yet even then you may have ambigious formats. You have to sanitize your inputs.

Comment: To say it differently: If your "missing" parts would only occur in one specific way, e.g. full date would be `20191003`, missing day would be `201910` and missing month and day would be `2019` you could work with the length and use moments `startOf("day")` / `startOf("month")` / startOf("year") to fill in the gaps. It all depends on the trustworthyness of your input though.

Answer (score 1):

You can get unused tokens from the moment object that gets created:

```
function getDateStr(date: string, format) {
    const m = moment(date, 'YYYYMMDD');
    const unused = m.parsingFlags().unusedTokens;
    format = format.split('-');
    format = format.filter(part => !unused.includes(part));
    format = format.join('-');
    return moment(date, 'YYYYMMDD').format(format);
}
```

Comment: Edited. `_pf` is a private field, should get tokens with a method `parsingFlags`.

Comment: it half works.. I still have the "-" character, now I get" -05-2016", I can just remove opening and closing "-", do you have any better idea maybe? and if I have only a year I get "--2016"

Comment: Edited, but only works for `-` delimiter. You'll have to know which delimiter is being used.

Comment: Main problem that I discovered- the unused is from the "YYYYMMDD", but the format can be "D-MM-YYYY" so if I give "201602" date "DD" will be redundant but it is not part of format..

Answer (score 0):

```
import moment from 'moment';

getDateStr(date: string, format){
    // you can directly use date, but it should be valid date

    return moment(date).format(format)
}
```

Comment: it does not work.. for "201605" I got "01-01-201605" for "DD-MM-YYYY" format.

Comment: I guess you have to pass one more parameter which can identify your input date format